# Error while separating uploading and processing of image, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

does anyone know why im getting this error? 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Site_model::get_images()'

entire model: http://pastebin.com/nKwEgjP8
controller: http://pastebin.com/fWpbiCWQ

process_image() was previously within do_upload() im trying to make them separate, anyone have an idea of what's up? all syntax checks say that's fine

**updated controller with }'s corrected:** pastebin.com/6Cxq1BWJ
it's now saying process_image() is undefined when its called from do_upload()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem is that you actually moved everything with and after the `do_upload()` method out of the `Site_model` class. And the rest (including `get_images()` has been moved inside the `do_upload()` function.

It's pretty must just a mess - the problem is that your curly brackets haven't been placed properly.

Comment: i fixed all the }'s now, but it's now saying "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function process_image()" on line 275 of the model

Comment: That's because you are refering to a function, not the class method; instead of just typing `process_image(...)` you need to refer to your class method like so: `$this->process_image(...)`